# Write recurrence relation for above algorithm and solve it using Iteration Method.

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Consider the following recursive algorithm for computing the sum of the first $n$ squares: $\sum \limits _{i=1} ^n i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2$.

Algorithm:

`SUM(n)
if n = 1 return 1
else return SUM(n − 1) + n ∗ n`

Write the recurrence relation for above algorithm and solve it using the iteration method.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a really minimalistic question without any further (i.e. your own) input.

Comment: The recurrence relation is already given in the form the the algorithm itself, therefore it is difficult to understand what answer you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

The given pseudo code

```
SUM(n)
if n = 1 return 1
else return SUM(n − 1) + n ∗ n
```

directly translates into the mathematical function definition
\begin{align}
s(1) &= 1 \\
s(n) &= s(n-1) + n^2
\end{align}

which is a recurrence relation
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 1 \\
x_n &= x_{n-1} + n^2 
\end{align}

The method of iteration seems to be looking at a couple of values and then deducing a closed form, which has to be proofed by some means like induction.

Inserting values for $n$ gives
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 1 \\
x_2 &= 1 + 2^2 \\
x_3 &= 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 \\
x_4 &= 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2
\end{align}
and leads to the assumption
$$
x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2
$$
as expected.

Comment: Thnx for guidline mvw

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** The result will look like a poylnomial of third degree:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = an^3+bn^2+cn+d
$$
Calculate three more values by hand (you already have $n=1$) and find the coefficients...

Comment: He doesn't want this, he wants to convert a recursive function into an iterative one (i.e. a "for loop"-based one).

Comment: thnx for guidline draks.....

Comment: @AlexM. oh, right, now I see...